# Tag synonym: compare->comparison

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I've whipped up a little tag wiki for [comparison], and untagged the four questions that were [compare].  I'd "suggest a synonym" for [compare], but I don't have 5 votes in it (neither, for that matter, does anyone else).

If I haven't consumed all my diamond-help for the day, could someone with super-cow powers do the deed?

Comment: Thankfully there's more than one super-cow awake to deal with it :)

Answer (score 2):

*BAMF*

A tag synonym has been born.

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAY!

Comment: Is that the sound a synonym makes when it's born??

Comment: It is when I create it whole out of the Ether.

Comment: Sounds more painful than joyful.

Comment: Is it possible for people who suggest tag synonyms like this to get the synonymizer badge?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't. It's one of the weaknesses of the synonym-making system.